# Access Repository to fragment presenter, in MVP model and dagger2

Tags: android, repository-pattern, dagger-2, android-mvp

I am using repository pattern in mvp with dagger .In **App scope** I binded my  RemoteDataSource and LocalDataSource:

```
@Binds
    @AppScope
    @Remote
    abstract MainDataSource RemoteDataSource(RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource);

    @Binds
    @AppScope
    @Local
    abstract MainDataSource LocalDataSource(LocalDataSource localDataSource);
```

And i injected main repository in app scope:

```
 @Inject
    public MainRepository(@Remote MainDataSource remoteDataSource,
                          @Local MainDataSource localDataSource) {
        this.remoteDataSource = checkNotNull(remoteDataSource);
        this.localDataSource = checkNotNull(localDataSource);
    }
```

Now in fragment scope in `mainpresenter` i passed **MainRepository** in it's contractor :

```
@MainFragScope
@Component(modules = {MainFragModule.class}, dependencies = AppComponent.class)
public interface MainFragComponent {
```

Presenter constructor:

```
private MainDataSource remoteDataSource;
private MainDataSource localDataSource;
 @Inject
    public MainPresenter(MainRepository repository, ArrayAdapter<String> typesAdapter) {
        this.repository = checkNotNull(repository);
        this.typesAdapter = checkNotNull(typesAdapter);
    }
@Override
public void loadChart(String district, String date, String type) {
    remoteDataSource.loadChart(district,date,type);
}
```

In `RemoteDataSource` i have a method called `loadChart` and it's job is fetch data from remote server by retrofit:

```
   public void loadChart(String district, String date, String type) {
        JsonObject joParam = new JsonObject();
        apiService.getAnalyticalReport(joParam).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // need presenter reference to pass response to it
```

After fetching data i need to return this data from server to fragment presenter(MainPresenter).I need to presenter reference. How could i get presenter without destroy **mvp** roles!!? Because in **AppScope** i do not access to **MainPresenter**.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO in native way, before solving the communication between `MainPresenter` and `remoteDataSource`, it could be nice solving the one that between `MainDataSource` and `MainRepository`firstly. Because there is a bridge something like this

Presenter --> MainRepository --> MainDataSource

`MainDataSource` and `MainRepository` could provide an interface for its users to communicate.  Also with this way, `MainDataSource` or `MainRepository` won't need MainPresenter

So the data transferring will be like this,

- MainRepository(Implements interface A) --> MainDataSource(provides
  interface A)
- MainPresenter(Implements interface B) --> MainRepository(provides
  interface B)

Comment: dude, do you have any example(simple project) to your description? @blackkara

Comment: Seems you are using also clean architecture. Check this [link](https://github.com/bufferapp/clean-architecture-components-boilerplate)

Comment: Most of projects, use RxJava2. In rx and retrofit you do not need do anything because with rx with retrofit you can have a return value but in retrofit alone, you can not return a value simply.I'll check recommended github project and announce you  .@blackkara

Comment: BTW, i started answering with 'in native way'. You can make simple the whole process with reactive way.  I hope it helps you :-)